# Get custom attribute value in multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many select elements like below , When any option is selected I need to get the value of   `data-cal`

```
  <select data-cal="89" name="caloriecalculator" style="width: 100px;">
                      <option value="100">Per 100g</option>
                      <option value="225">1 cup, mashed </option>
                      <option value="150">1 cup, sliced </option>
    </select>

    <select data-cal="109" name="caloriecalculator" style="width: 100px;">
                      <option value="100">Per 100g</option>
                      <option value="225">1 cup</option>
                      <option value="150">1 cup big</option>
    </select>
```

My jquery code

```
$('select[name="caloriecalculator"]').change(function() {
//I need to get the data atribute (data-cal) of select here.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method, like this

```
$('select[name="caloriecalculator"]').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('cal') );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/letoje/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$('select[name="caloriecalculator"]').change(function() {
    var cal = $(this).data('cal');
});
```

?